# Pass data between several views in MVC applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am creating a MVC application and I would like to pass data between views.
Here is my first view:

```
@model ClassDeclarationsThsesis.Models.AddGroupViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Groups";
}

<h2>Add Groups to subjects</h2>

@foreach (var user in Model.Users)
{
    if (user.email.Replace(" ", String.Empty) == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)
    {
        if (user.user_type.Replace(" ", String.Empty) == 3.ToString() || user.user_type.Replace(" ", String.Empty) == 2.ToString())
        {
            using (Html.BeginForm("AddGroup", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Create new groups.</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @{
                        List<SelectListItem> listItems1 = new List<SelectListItem>();

                    }
                    @foreach (var subject in Model.Subjects)
                    {
                        listItems1.Add(new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = subject.name,
                            Value = subject.name,
                            Selected = true
                        });
                    }
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.subject_name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.subject_name, listItems1, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.qty, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.qty, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                            }
                        }
                        if (user.user_type.Replace(" ", String.Empty) == 1.ToString())
                        {
                            <p>You do not have enough permissions to enter this page. Contact the administrator.</p>
                                }

                            }
                        }
```

And my controller for this:

```
public ActionResult AddGroup(AddGroupViewModel model)
{
    var entities = new ClassDeclarationsDBEntities1();
    var model1 = new AddGroupViewModel();
    model1.Subjects = entities.Subjects.ToList();
    model1.Users = entities.Users.ToList();
    // set your other properties too?


    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        return RedirectToAction("AddGroupsQty", "Account");
    }
    return View(model1);
}
```

And what I would like to achieve is to pass chosen item from dropdown list and this qty variable to AddGroupsQty View. How do I do this? In my controller of AddGroupsQty i have just a simple return of view so far.

Comment: Is there a route to the new view in your RouteConfig.cs? Or are you attempting to reshow the current view based on an input's changed value?

Comment: @Mmcgowa3 No, I did not add any route there. I am just trying to show a different view depending on input of this view.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the values using querystring.

```
return RedirectToAction("AddGroupsQty", "Account", 
                                         new { qty=model.qty,subject=model.subject_name);
```

Assuming your `AddGroupsQty` have 2 parameters to accept the quantity and subject

```
public ActionResult AddGroupsQty(int qty,string subject)
{
  // do something with the parameter
  // to do : return something
}
```

This will make browser to issue a new GET request with the values in query string. If you do not prefer to do that, you can use a server side temporary persistence mecahnism like TempData

```
TempData["qty"]=model.qty;
TempData["subject"]= model.subject_name;
return RedirectToAction("AddGroupsQty", "Account");
```

And in your `AddGroupsQty` action,

```
public ActionResult AddGroupsQty()
{
  int qty=0;
  string subjectName=string.Empty;
  if(TempData["qty"]!=null)
  {
    qty = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["qty"]);
  }
  if(TempData["subject"]!=null)
  {
    subjectName = TempData["subject"];
  }
  // Use this as needed
  return View();
}
```

If you want to pass these values from the ADdGroupsQty action to it's view, you can use either a view model or ViewBag/ViewData.